# Reading 'CSV' files with Python, that are not actually CSV dialects

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have some files, that, by the terms of Python's `csv` module, seem to be non-CSV files.

However, the approach is not totally different, they have just a couple odd properties, such as:

- Columns are separated by single space
- Quoting is done by four space characters
- No way to escape qouting

Anyway, it seems that the rows are generated by a regular grammar, so I think parsing them with `re` module can be a no-brainer.

My code already uses `DictReader` for CSV files, but I need to read these oddly formatted files as well.

Is there any way to adapt Python's `csv` module to read these files, or should I create custom classes that act like `DictReader`, but do not inherit from anything in the  `csv` module?

Comment: Have you tried anything with `csv`'s built-in [dialect options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The four spaces used for quoting can't be handled by that.

Comment: Yep! But my quoting is not a single character string.

Comment: Will there ever be two or three spaces in a row (corresponding to one or two empty columns)?

Comment: @TimPietzcker yeah, that's possible.

Comment: Are there 9 spaces between two quoted columns (two quotes + delimiter), and 5 spaces between a quoted and a non-quoted column?

Comment: @JanneKarila what's more surprising, after a look at the file: there is 4, when the left-hand side column is quoted, regardless what the right-hand side column is (quoted or not).

Comment: So the rules aren't really consistent, then? Can you provide a sample of such a file that exhibits all the characteristics that need to be handled?

Comment: For me personally, this is not a problem anymore. (The files will be in a different format). For those who may have a similar problem, @TimPietzcker's answer can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is more complicated than I first thought (at least for a regex solution). Or maybe there's a simpler one I can't think of. The following regex seems to work for all cases:

```
reobj = re.compile(
    """(?:        # Start of non-capturing group:
     [^ \r\n]+    # Match one or more characters except space or newlines
    |             # or
     [ ]{4}       # match a quoted section, starting with four spaces,
     (?:          # then the following non-capturing group
      (?![ ]{4})  # (but only if no four spaces are at the current position)
      .           # which matches any character
     )*           # any number of times,
     [ ]{4}       # ending with four spaces.
    )+            # Repeat that as often as needed (at least one match)
    |             # OR: Match the empty space between two single spaces
    (?<![^ ])     # which means there mustn't be a non-space character before
    (?<!(?<![ ])[ ]{4}) # nor exactly spaces before the current position,
    (?= |$)       # but there must be a space or the end of the line after it""", 
    re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL)
```

Result:

```
>>> reobj.findall("""foo bar baz    escape    bam foo    match with
... embedded newlines       crash boom  bang!""")
['foo', 'bar', 'baz    escape    bam', 'foo    match with\nembedded newlines    ',
 '', '', 'crash', 'boom', '', 'bang!']
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/fU2rC5).